# How to create a 2d quadrilateral mesh out of a pointcloud and plot it using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a 2D quadrilateral mesh out of pointcloud and plot it using the matplotlib library

my points look like:

```
points = [
    [2.9600000000000004, 6.3999999999999995],
    [2.72, 4.8],
    [2.48, 3.1999999999999997],
    [2.2399999999999998, 1.5999999999999996],
    [4.32, 6.3999999999999995],
    [4.24, 4.8],
    [4.16, 3.1999999999999997],
    [4.08, 1.5999999999999996],
    [5.68, 6.3999999999999995],
    [5.759999999999999, 4.8],
    [5.84, 3.1999999999999997],
    [5.92, 1.5999999999999996],
    [7.04, 6.3999999999999995],
    [7.28, 4.8],
    [7.5200000000000005, 3.1999999999999997],
    [7.76, 1.5999999999999996],
    [0, 0],
    [2.0, 0.0],
    [4.0, 0.0],
    [6.0, 0.0],
    [8.0, 0.0],
    [10, 0],
    [2, 8],
    [3.2, 8.0],
    [4.4, 8.0],
    [5.6, 8.0],
    [6.8, 8.0],
    [8, 8],
    [2, 8],
    [1.6, 6.4],
    [1.2, 4.8],
    [0.7999999999999998, 3.1999999999999993],
    [0.3999999999999999, 1.5999999999999996],
    [0, 0],
    [8, 8],
    [8.4, 6.4],
    [8.8, 4.8],
    [9.2, 3.1999999999999993],
    [9.6, 1.5999999999999996],
    [10, 0]
]
```

I have tried numpy's meshgrid tool but I couldn't manage to get it to work. I would appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance,

Sebastian

Comment: Seems pretty simple: *Make N-D coordinate arrays for vectorized evaluations of N-D scalar/vector fields over N-D grids, given one-dimensional coordinate arrays x1, x2,..., xn.*  `:(`

Comment: i did. x,y = zip(*poins)
        X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y), but i can't plot it